# How to monitor the network usage of specific apps on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, monitoring

I am currently helping someone who has experienced large amounts of data being transferred over her DSL connection. After long research (via IRC support) I found out that her iPhone is obviously sending lots of data, i.e. several hundred kbyte/s, as soon as she connects it to her home network. The iPhone itself seems to work fine.

To find the culprit responsible for these huge amounts of data I would probably need to find a way to measure how much data all connected applications are sending within a specific interval.

As I do not use an Apple mobile device myself I am not familiar with iOS. Are there any possibilities to get information about the network usage of specific apps, either natively or with the help of a third-party application that is for free or at least offers a free trial version?

Comment: Please ask for this feature at Apple so they'll consider adding it. The more people that ask the more likely it will get added http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [**Onavo Count**](http://www.onavo.com/apps/iphone_count)

> Onavo Count monitors and analyzes all types of mobile data and phone use. This includes background, foreground, and Wi-Fi use.
>
> [image: Onavo Count]

Comment: This app is no longer available from the UK or US app stores.

Answer (score 2):

iOS can do this natively under network usage. Just reset the stats with the bottom button and review later.

Go under Settings > Cellular and scroll down. You will see what each app installed on her device uses as far as data. (This is on iOS 7)

Comment: For previous versions, go Settings >> General >> Usage >> Cellular Usage

Comment: This option is labelled "Mobile data" in the UK. It's not much use for apps that only use WiFi though :-(